# MySQL order by 2 date columns by whichever is greater

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across an issue today debugging some code: given the following
MySQL  data snippet:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id ║ date_created        ║ date_updated        ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 2015-12-07 15:04:21 ║ 2016-06-06 10:59:25 ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 2016-06-06 10:59:25 ║ 2016-09-09 09:44:58 ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 2016-09-09 09:44:59 ║ 2017-11-30 11:36:37 ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 4  ║ 2017-11-30 11:36:37 ║ null                ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I need to sort these dates accordingly:

1. If an entry's `date_updated` is `null` then use its `date_created`
2. If an entry's `date_updated > date_created` then use its `date_updated` (although this should always be the case)
3. If two entries A, B are compared, where A only has a `date_created` and B's `date_updated` is not null and these two values are equal, then A should be ordered greater then B.

So my expected outcome should be:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id ║ date_created        ║ date_updated        ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 4  ║ 2017-11-30 11:36:37 ║ null                ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 2016-09-09 09:44:59 ║ 2017-11-30 11:36:37 ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 2016-06-06 10:59:25 ║ 2016-09-09 09:44:58 ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 2015-12-07 15:04:21 ║ 2016-06-06 10:59:25 ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table t
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN t.date_updated IS NOT NULL AND t.date_updated > t.dated_created
    THEN t.date_created
    ELSE t.date_updated
  END
DESC
```

However this doesn't order correctly according to point 2.
What would the correct MySQL statement here?

Comment: You are simply mixing up the dates. When you detect that there is a `date_updated` you want to use, you mistakenly use `date_created` instead.

Comment: A simplified solution would be to store date_created value as initial date_updated value for all records (instead of keeping it null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_updated` shall have precedence over `date_created`. Use `COALESCE` for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
ORDER BY COALESCE(date_updated, date_created) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your case statement is incorrect. By mistake, you have interchanged the  t.date_updated and t.date_created  (check line number 5 and 6 in below SQL query)

**Try this**

```
SELECT * FROM table t
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN t.date_updated IS NOT NULL AND t.date_updated > t.dated_created
    THEN t.date_updated
    ELSE t.date_created
  END
DESC
```